# Why does Rspec ignore default_url_options that I set in application_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've overridden method default_url_options in application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  def redirect_to_root
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def default_url_options(options={})
      { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
    end

    def set_locale
      if params[:locale].blank?
        logger.debug "* Accept-Language: #{request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}"
        abbr = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
        I18n.locale = if Language.find_by(abbr: abbr).nil?
                        logger.debug "* Unknown Language"
                        I18n.default_locale
                      else
                        abbr
                      end
        logger.debug "* Locale set to '#{I18n.locale}'"
      else
        I18n.locale = params[:locale]
      end
    end

    def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
      request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
    end
end
```

It works good.
But when I start controller tests they all fail. For example:

```
it "renders show template" do
  get :show, id: @book.id
  expect(response).to render_template :show
end

ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
no route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :id=>"1"}
```

Why does rspec not pass defautl url option (locale) that I set in ApplicationController?And how can tell rspec to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but with a test of an ActionMailer class. It is not an ActionController and therefore `default_url_options` was not called.

I had to configure default locale in configuration:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3001', :locale => :de}
end
```

Maybe there is a similar line in your configuration which overrides the `url_options`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
config.before(:each, type: :request) do
  default_url_options[:locale] ||= I18n.default_locale
end
```

in a helper that you call in your test file (`rails_helper.rb` for example).

See: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255